# why outer for loop not completing whole in one go rather than passing control to inner for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

why the outer for loop is not completing in first go rather than its passing control to inner for loop and the inner one is completing fully and then coming back with the previous value of outer for loop please correct me if i am wrong some where

here is code

```
//nested loop
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j;
  
  // Outer loop
  for (i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
    printf("Outer: %d\n", i);  // Executes 2 times
    
    // Inner loop
    for (j = 1; j <= 3; ++j) {
      printf(" Inner: %d\n", j);  // Executes 6 times (2 * 3)
    }
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

i expected this

```
Outer: 1
Outer: 2
Inner: 1
Inner: 2
Inner: 3
```

Comment: What's inside `{  }` is one unit that the loop executes each time.

Comment: Why do you call it "outer loop" if you expect it to *not* include the whole other (inner) loop?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing sequential loops with nested loops.  If two loops are sequential (at the same level, not nested), then (1) the first loop runs to completion, then (2) the second loop runs to completion.  This is the behavior you were looking for.

But when two loops are nested, the inner loop runs from start to finish *for each iteration* of the outer loop.  So (1) the first iteration of the outer loop starts, (2) the inner loop runs from start to finish, (3) the second iteration of the outer loop starts, (4) the inner loop runs from start to finish, etc.  The total number of iterations of the inner loop is the product of the number of iterations of the outer loop times the number of iterations of the inner loop by itself.

Answer (score 0):

When the for loop makes it's check `i <= 2`, it will do one of two things:

- If the check fails (i.e. evaluates to false), it will skip to immediately after the closing curly bracket associated with the for loop's curly opening bracket.
- If the check passes (i.e. evaluates to true), it will execute all of the instructions inside the for loop's curly braces, then increment i and run the check again.

Your curly braces contain the following:

```
printf("Outer: %d\n", i);  // Executes 2 times

// Inner loop
for (j = 1; j <= 3; ++j) {
  printf(" Inner: %d\n", j);  // Executes 6 times (2 * 3)
}
```

This means that every time i is less than or equal to 2, it will execute this entire block of code before making the check again.

In order to get the output you're expecting, you don't want nested for-loops. Instead, you want to move the inner for-loop out:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
    printf("Outer: %d\n", i);
}

for (j = 1; j <= 3; ++j) {
    printf(" Inner: %d\n", j);
}
```